# How to redirect mingw output to a file

Tags: mingw, msys2

I use msys2 on windows.
Is it possible to redirect the mingw output to a file ?
I tried to redirect the mintty output with no success.
Thanks for your help

Some precisions :
I want to compile the openssl project on a windows platform using mingw. Under Linux, the sequence is : ./config then make clean the make then make test. Under mingw the sequence should be mingw64 ./config, then mingw64 make clean, then mingw64 make, then mingw64 make test. This sequence works but I want to redirect the outputs of mingw64 to a file. mingw64 is a mintty windows terminal. I can't find to do this redirection. Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: Apart from diagnostics, the output of mingw *is* a file. Do you mean you want to redirect the diagnostics to a file?

Comment: It's really hard to help with so little information.  MinGW is a runtime used for many different Windows programs, so I have no idea what program you ran, how you redirected its output to a file, or how you checked the contents of the file.  Please post a shell session that shows what commands you ran and how you checked that the file was empty (e.g. run `ls -l somefile.txt` as the last step to see how many bytes are in the file).